# QGIS automatic fill of the attribute table by expression

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, string

I have a line layer and in the attribute list the "Name" column, which can be, for example, 'V1','V2',....'V1-2','V1-2-3',... in I'm trying to put an expression in the next column that is essentially only '1' or '2' or '3' and that:

- 1 - when the name is without '-', i.e. 'V1' or 'V2' or 'V3'
- 2 - when it has only one '-', for example 'V2-3', 'V10-1' and so on
- other variants should be marked as '3'.

I tried:

```
If( "NameVlake" like '%-%',If( "NameVlake" like '%-%-%',If( "NameVlake" like '%-%-%-%',If( "NameVlake" like '% -%-%-%-%',If( "Train Name" like '%-%-%-%-%-%',3),3),3),2),1)
```

even this

```
CASE
WHEN "name" LIKE '%-__%' THEN '3'
WHEN "name" LIKE '%-_%' THEN '2'
ELSE '1'
end
```

I didn't succeed.

---

EDIT:
@Mayo
I tried to enter your code as the default value in the Attribute form

```
CASE
   WHEN array_length(string_to_array("name", '-')) = 1 THEN 1
   WHEN array_length(string_to_array("name", '-')) = 2 THEN 2
   ELSE 3
END
```

but everything is marked as '3'...

It might be important (!?) the "Name" column is a string, as well as the "Order" column
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
CASE
   WHEN array_length(string_to_array("name", '-')) = 1 THEN 1
   WHEN array_length(string_to_array("name", '-')) = 2 THEN 2
   ELSE 3
END
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is to count the number of `-` characters in a string and code this with values from 1 (0 occurrence) to 2 (1 occurrence) to 3 (all other cases).

For this, you can use regular expressions:

1. use the function [`regex_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) to replace all characters except `-` (in regular expressions: `[^-]`) with an empty string `''`
2. then count the length of the resulting string (containing only the `-` characters from the input) with the function [`length()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-string-length)
3. add 1: `+1`
4. and finally use the function [`clamp()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#clamp) to limit the results to a range from 1 to 3.

So the expression looks as follows:

```
clamp(
    1,
    length(regexp_replace(Naziv,'[^-]',''))+1,
    3
)
```

[image]